# Does the RSpec DSL violate the law of Demeter?

Tags: ruby, rspec, law-of-demeter

This may be a naive question, but does RSpec's testing DSL violate the law of Demeter?

Here's an example of the RSpec DSL from http://rspec.info:

```
bowling.score.should eq(0)
```

From a Demeter perspective, this seems to me indistinguishable from this example:

```
user.department.try(:name)
```

which according to Avdi Grimm *is* a violation of the Law of Demeter.

Source: http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/

Comment: Just a note, that is the documentation for RSpec 1, which is probably not what you want. RSpec 2 lives at http://relishapp.com/rspec.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I think the RSpec example is still representative though, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. The RSpec 1 site is annoyingly lacking any link to the RSpec 2 docs, though, which can cause lots of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously subjective, but I believe it **does not**.

The `should` call is part of the *language* of RSpec, which just happens to be built upon Ruby. There's no reason it couldn't be:

```
should_be_equal(bowling.score, 0)
```

(or similar) but that's not the language of RSpec. Further, the `should` method only exists on that object within specs, for the specs.

To try and (somewhat crudely, perhaps) better illustrate my argument about being a part of the language:

```
bowling.score + 10
```

is actually calling the `+` method on `score`, but would you see this as a law of demeter violation? The `+` is seen as an operator rather than a method, much like `should` be above.

Comment: What if proponents of `try` said something similar about `try`: that it should be considered a pseudo-operator, instead of a method? Would that argument hold water too? Why or why not?

Comment: `try` in your example above *is* a law of demeter violation because you're essentially calling `user.department.name`, just with some protection if `department` is `nil`. `user.try(:department)`, though, would not violate the law of demeter.

Comment: That makes sense. So are you saying that Ruby DSLs are exempt from having to follow the Law of Demeter?

Comment: It probably depends. When you're trying to express something as a language, it's not really so much a method call on the object. Further, law of demeter doesn't really matter as much in tests in the first place: I think if you're doing unit tests properly it will encourage you to flush out law of demeter violations in your code because they make mocking/stubbing much more difficult.

Comment: OK I think I'm satisfied with that.

Answer (score 2):

Demeter is a risk-reduction guideline motivated by the idea that the less one
part of the system depends on the structure of other parts, the less likely
that part will be impacted by changes to said structure.

You could certainly argue that `game.score.should eq(0)` is a Demeter
violation, but the `should` method is part of the rspec framework, which is the
context around the statement `game.score.should eq(0)` and is not likely to
change in a way that would force changes to this statement.

Maybe it violates Demeter, maybe it doesn't, but the risk that Demeter aims to address is not
really present.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thank you for the explanation.